# How to display notifications in Angular 2

Tags: angular, notifications

In AngularJS (version 1.x) , we had [ng-notify](http://matowens.github.io/ng-notify/) for displaying notifications,we would like to know
how to implement the same in Angular 2.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: try this: https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications OR you can create your own.

Comment: you can make use of ng2-notify or you can write your own notify (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-notify).

Comment: I can recommend "ng2-toastr" (npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr) providing notifications for alerts, infos, ...; Very useful and flexible

Comment: try https://shubhi1407.github.io/ng2-notify-popup/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used the PrimeNG package which include a lot of UI components,
there messages component to display notifications:
[PrimeNG - Messages Component](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/messages)

Answer (score 6):

If we are creating complete FE of some app we are using Angular2 material  which has implemented snack bar.

https://github.com/angular/material2

https://material.angular.io/components

Or you can easily integrate toaster that will show nice material toasts
https://github.com/PointInside/ng2-toastr

I can strongly recommend both and both were tested in production (though material library is currently still beta)

Comment: toaster is simple n easy to use :)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is **ng2-toasty**

Below are steps:

1)Install using - `npm install ng2-toasty --save`

2)Update systemjs.config.js

```
System.config({
    map: {
        'ng2-toasty': 'node_modules/ng2-toasty/bundles/index.umd.js'
    }
});
```

3) Import ToastyModule

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastyModule} from 'ng2-toasty';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ToastyModule.forRoot()
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

4) Use the ToastyService for your application

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ToastyService, ToastyConfig, ToastOptions, ToastData} from 'ng2-toasty';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <div>Hello world</div>
        <button (click)="addToast()">Add Toast</button>
        <ng2-toasty></ng2-toasty>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private toastyService:ToastyService, private toastyConfig: ToastyConfig) { 
        // Assign the selected theme name to the `theme` property of the instance of ToastyConfig. 
        // Possible values: default, bootstrap, material
        this.toastyConfig.theme = 'material';
    }

    addToast() {
        // Just add default Toast with title only
        this.toastyService.default('Hi there');
        // Or create the instance of ToastOptions
        var toastOptions:ToastOptions = {
            title: "My title",
            msg: "The message",
            showClose: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            theme: 'default',
            onAdd: (toast:ToastData) => {
                console.log('Toast ' + toast.id + ' has been added!');
            },
            onRemove: function(toast:ToastData) {
                console.log('Toast ' + toast.id + ' has been removed!');
            }
        };
        // Add see all possible types in one shot
        this.toastyService.info(toastOptions);
        this.toastyService.success(toastOptions);
        this.toastyService.wait(toastOptions);
        this.toastyService.error(toastOptions);
        this.toastyService.warning(toastOptions);
    }
}
```

Simple demo available here - http://akserg.github.io/ng2-webpack-demo/#/toasty

Sample code available here - https://github.com/akserg/ng2-systemjs-demo

Comment: What can I do If I use Webpack?

Answer (score 1):

[ng2-notify-popup](https://shubhi1407.github.io/ng2-notify-popup/) for Angular 2 is based on [ng-notify](https://github.com/matowens/ng-notify). You can try using that.

Answer (score 1):

Check this npm package, it's super easy to use and may be just what do you need!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ntf

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with a [Snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview)

Import

```
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
```

Displaying:

```
let snackBarRef = snackBar.open('Message archived');
```

Callbacks:

```
snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('The snack-bar was dismissed');
});


snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('The snack-bar action was triggered!');
});

snackBarRef.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommanded 'angular2-notifications' is easy and flexible to use.

for more details and Demo : https://jaspero.co/resources/projects/ng-alerts

Moreover we can to make alers to push them with ng2-alerts